# How to copy a multidimensional array to another without knowing the exact amount of rows in C?

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

So my program is basically built to get game scores, and track w/l/t, etc. What I am needed to do is to arrange the scores in ascending order based off of the opponent's scores.
So to do that I decided to bubble sort, but when I do that and print it, the first pair [0][0], and [0][1] come out with big negative numbers, which is what I'm guessing is their reference then after that the rest print correctly. I've googled around and couldn't find anything about this so I was wanting to copy the original array into a copy and try sorting with that one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS //doesn't work
#define FLUSH myFlush()
#define GAMES 50

void titleDisplay(int);
void menuOptions();
void gameResults(int *counter, int team[][2], int); // records games from user input
void showRecord(int counter, int team[][2]); // shows current record
void displayResultFromGamesWon(int counter, int team[][2]);
void displayAllResults(int counter, int team[][2]); // shows all results ordered by opp score.
char getChoice();
void myFlush();

int main() {
    //const int GAMES = 50; - program doesn't read this as a const when used to create arr.
    const int MAX_GAMES = 50;
    int userTeam[GAMES][2]; // array column 0 is  user score, column 1 is opp score
    int gameCounter = 0;
    char userChoice;

    do {
        system("clear");
        titleDisplay(1);
        menuOptions();
        userChoice = getChoice();
        switch (userChoice) {
        case 'a': case 'A':
            gameResults(&gameCounter, userTeam, MAX_GAMES);
            break;
        case 'b': case 'B':
            showRecord(gameCounter, userTeam);
            break;
        case 'c': case 'C':
            displayResultFromGamesWon(gameCounter, userTeam);
            break;
        case 'd': case 'D':
            displayAllResults(gameCounter, userTeam);
            break;
        case 'e': case 'E':
            printf("Bye bye.\n");
            system("pause");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid selection, choose again!\n");
            system("pause");
            break;
        }//end switch
    } while (userChoice != 'e' && userChoice != 'E');
    return 0;
}
```

Here's where I sort and print:

```
//function definition
void displayAllResults(int counter, int team[][2]) {
    int i;
    int temp, temp2 = 0;
    system("clear");
    if (counter == 0) {
        printf("\n\n\tYou haven't played any games yet.\n\n\n");
    }
    else {
        titleDisplay(4);
        printf("\t  (Arranged by Opponent score low to high)\n\n");
        printf("\tUser Score\t\t\tOpponent Score\n");
        printf("\t----------\t\t\t--------------\n");
        //begin bubble sorting 
        for (int x = 0; x < counter; x++) {
            for (int y = x + 1; y < counter; y++) {
                if (team[x][0] > team[y][0]) {
                    temp = team[x][1];
                    temp2 = team[x][0];
                    team[x][0] = team[y][0];
                    team[x][1] = team[y][1];
                    team[y][0] = temp2;
                    team[y][1] = temp;
                }//end if
            }
        }//end bubble sort
        for (i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            printf("\t%-8i\t\t\t%-11i\n", team[i][0], team[i][1]);
        }//end for
    }//end else
    system("pause");
}//end function
```

I've tried declaring a variable of 'int sortedArray = team[counter][2];' in the displayAllResults function but that gave memory problems, and failed when I tried to access that variable. I tried memcpy, but either I didn't implement correctly or that doesn't work either.

Is it even possible to copy a 2D array like this to another one?

Comment: I don't see where you are trying to copy arrays. All I see is a bad attempt at bubble sort, featuring the number `5`. What is that `5` doing  there?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. sorry, that 5 isn't suppose to be there, it was a test number-- changed it to 'counter' forgot to updated it, when i updated the x parameters. And sorry about the bubble sort it was the best I could come up with to sort through columns and not rows. I should note I'm a beginner. Edit: also, i deleted the code of trying to copy arrays because it wasn't working so felt like it was a waste of line.

Comment: Please post only relevant code. If you don't know how to copy an array, post a [mcve] that demonstrates your attempt at copying an array, and does nothing else.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to copy an array to another:
1-Using sizeof(array) and dividing it to size of one element of the array, in this case it is a pointer.
2- The best way is, to have a variable which will show you the length of the array.

I think you made an implementational mistake. I couldn't understand what you are doing. What is 5 for?
In any case, do have a variable for the length of the array.

Comment: I fixed the 5, it was suppose to be counter, not 5. But I don't exactly have the length of the array, i mean it is predetermined at '50', but the user may not input 50 games, which is where my gameCounter variable comes into play to access x amount of rows in the array if that makes any sense. I'm just trying to sort through the columns so I can print scores in ascending order based off the opp's score. i.e 
user: 12
opp: 90
and then the next game would have
user: 15
opp: 13
it would print the 2nd game score over the 1st game score since 13 < 90

Comment: It is very normal to have an error by saying "I suppose" for something done in your code. Be confident about what you are doing please.

Comment: If you know the limit, you can give null to the empty arrays